# What is the fewest number of days required to run this conference?

Tags: algorithm

I'm an IT person / math geek helping to organize a conference. The times (but not the days) for events during the conference are set in stone. For instance, we know that a certain event will occur between 1pm and 3pm on some day. I'm trying to write a script that determines the fewest number of days in which we can run the conference and have no overlapping events.

All events occur within a day; no event has a time that crosses 12am or spans several days.

My first shot at this question involved modeling it as an undirected graph. We can let events be represented as vertices, and an edge between two vertices mark that two events overlap. Then, the problem is reduced to finding the graph's minimum chromatic number - the fewest number of colors it takes to color the vertices while ensuring that the endpoints of every edge differ in color.

However, I am unable to develop an efficient dynamic programming algorithm that runs in polynomial time to compute the chromatic number.

Any other leads? This seems like an NP-complete problem, but I bet we can solve it in polynomial time with a clever time-space tradeoff, ie dynamic programming.

Comment: It is indeed an NP-complete problem (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring). You can try and use an approximation algorithm, or look for other representations / solutions. This sounds similar to an AI project I had on university. Have you considered using something like an A* search with a good heuristic function?

Comment: @Filipe: No, coloring of interval graphs is not NP-hard. In fact it's very easy to solve.

Comment: @NiklasB. Hum, nice to know! Always learning. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your graph is an [interval graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph) the problem is much easier to solve then for general graphs using a sweep line algorithm. Let's say your events are represented as tuples `(s_i, f_i)`, where `s_i` is the start time of an event and `f_i` is the finish time (both in hours).

You can then use the following algorithm:

```
events := union of {(f_i, -1), (s_i, 1)} for all i
sort events lexicographically
answer := 0
count := 0
for (time, c) in events:
    count += c
    answer := max(answer, count)

return answer
```

Time complexity: `O(n log n)` or even `O(n)` if we assume a bounded number of possible times (which is likely to be the case in practice).

Comment: What's it mean to sort events lexicographically?

Comment: @DavidFaux: [`(a,b) < (c,d) :<=> a < c || (a == c && b < d)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order#Definition). This is just relevant if you have pairs `i`, `j` with `f_i = s_j`. In that case you have to decide whether it counts as an overlap or not (this particular algorithm decides that it is not an overlap. If it should be one, just order `1` before `-1` during the lexicographical comparison).

Comment: Wow, this is brilliant! Thanks. That worked for our events. I'm still staring at this trying to understand the intuition behind it though. haha Why -1 for end times?

Comment: @David: The intuition is actually very simple! Just imagine drawing the intervals on a piece of paper underneath each other, aligned with a time line. You start moving a vertical line from left to right, and whenever your vertical (sweep) line touches a new interval, you increment a counter in your mind because it is now intersecting the sweep line. As soon as you hit its end point, you decrease the counter, because it no longer intersects your line. At every point you know how many intervals intersect the sweep line and the maximum of all of those values is the chromatic number

Answer (score 1):

It is not NP problem, in terms of graphs - it is [critical path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method), but I do not see any mention that events are related to each other (ie order of events is not defined), to solve this

1. create array with 24 hours [0-23] (0 initialized)
2. run through all events and add add 1 to each hour it is occupied (for event from 1pm to 3pm - add to 13th and 14th only)
3. find max number in array - this will give you how many events are actually overlapped by time, so this is the minimal duration of conference (max can be found during stage 2)

So, actually it is O(N) problem